# C# using HttpListener and Request.ServerVariables on Windows Forms or Console

Tags: c#, windows, forms, httplistener, request.servervariables

**Project Objectives:**
Create a local Proxy Judge using a Console or Windows Form application for debugging and testing connections.

1. Project must request and receive proxy ServerVariables to display on client side.
2. Parse IPAddress and return Anonymity state.
3. Implement Basic Athentifcation Scheme.
4. Project must not use Scripts for functionality (e.g) PHP, Perl, Asp, etc.
5. Multi-platform Compatible (possibilty)

[image]

---

**Questions:**

1. Is it possible to use Request.ServerVariables on a local Windows or Console Application or is it ASP specific?
2. If this method is ASP specific is there another way to request the ServerVariables from a browser session?
3. If the method above is possible what is the proper approach for achieving this functionality?
4. What is a good example for verifing/Setting the Basic Authentification Scheme here? Like setting the password and user to be used and so on.

---

**References used:**
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpapplication.aspx
http://www.java2s.com/Code/CSharpAPI/System.Net/HttpListenerContextResponseStatusCode.htm
http://en.cship.org/wiki/ProxyJudge

**Example Code:**

```
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Collections.Specialized;

namespace IPJudge
{
    public class IPJudgeClass : IHttpModule
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            using (HttpListener listener = new HttpListener())
            {
                listener.AuthenticationSchemes = AuthenticationSchemes.None;
                listener.Prefixes.Add("http://localhost:8080/");
                //listener.Prefixes.Add("https://localhost/");
                listener.Start();

                HttpListenerContext ctx = listener.GetContext();
                ctx.Response.StatusCode = 200;
                string name = ctx.Request.QueryString["name"];

                StreamWriter writer = new StreamWriter(ctx.Response.OutputStream);
                writer.WriteLine("<P>Hello, {0}</P>", name);
                writer.WriteLine("<ul>");
                foreach (string header in ctx.Request.Headers.Keys)
                {
                    writer.WriteLine("<li><b>{0}:</b> {1}</li>", header, ctx.Request.Headers[header]);
                }
                writer.WriteLine("</ul>");

                writer.Close();
                ctx.Response.Close();
                listener.Stop();
            }
        }

        public void Init(HttpApplication app)
        {

            app.AcquireRequestState += new System.EventHandler(app_AcquireRequestState);
            app.PostAcquireRequestState += new System.EventHandler(app_PostAcquireRequestState);
        }

        public void app_AcquireRequestState(object o, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)o;
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;
            ctx.Response.Write(" Executing AcquireRequestState ");
            ctx.Response.Close();
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            // TODO:
            // Add code to clean up the
            // instance variables of a module.
        }

        public void app_PostAcquireRequestState(object o, System.EventArgs e)
        {
            HttpApplication httpApp = (HttpApplication)o;
            HttpContext ctx = HttpContext.Current;

            string remotehost  = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["REMOTE_ADDR"];
            string httpuseragent = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_USER_AGENT"];
            string requstmethod = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["REQUEST_METHOD"];
            string httpreferer = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_REFERER"];
            string HTTPXFORWARDEDFOR = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            string HTTPFORWARDEDFOR = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR"];
            string HTTPXFORWARDED = ctx.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_FORWARDED"];


            ctx.Response.Write("<P>REMOTE_ADDR: " + remotehost + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>HTTP_USER_AGENT: " + httpuseragent + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>REQUEST_METHOD: " + httpuseragent + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>HTTP_REFERER: " + httpreferer + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>HTTP_X_FORWARDED_FOR: " + httpreferer + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>HTTP_FORWARDED_FOR: " + httpreferer + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Write("<P>HTTP_X_FORWARDED: " + httpreferer + "</P>");
            ctx.Response.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code is merging ASP.NET logic and Application logic, which can't/shouldn't be done.

A `IHttpModule` is run by IIS in a ASP.NET WEB application

A `Main` method is run by a console application

Questions:

1. Request.ServerVariables can only be accessed on the web server
2. The method that you have (app_PostAcquireRequestState) where you are outputing the variables to the response stream, is how i do it. But not normally in a HttpModule or in that particular method. Try to output the variables towards the end of the ASP.NET pipeline.
3. You could turn on the tracing in web.config `<trace>`, that should output some of the variables you require.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6915t83k.aspx

1. Not sure what you are talking about here, do you have some example code.

Comment: Sorry, you misunderstood the ?. This is a ProxyJudge. So the actions of this application would be to act as a server on its own without a dedicated webserver application and wait for a  connection on the prefixed address:port, Once a connection is established it sends a request for the servervariables and resends the answer back to the browser for verification. The reason I am using IhttpModule is to inherit the functionality of retrieving the servervariables. Also I already know how about Console entry points work this is a class ;) and Web.config is out of the question as IIS is not used.

Comment: Umm the only example of working code is this
Example code: http://en.cship.org/wiki/ProxyJudge Hope that helps you understand. :)

Comment: The HttpListener is a simple layer over a socket connection. You require IIS to run HttpModules.

Comment: Thats more like it. So how would I get the servervariables then? Not using IIS or HttoModules?

Comment: ServerVariables seem to only be created from IIS/ASP.NET, the HttpListenerRequest object does not have any. But that makes sense, IIS uses ServerVariables to tell your ASP.NET application how it is being run. If you are using HttpListener then you dont need ServerVariables because you have full control over the application that is hosting the HttpListener.

Comment: So I have to resort to raw HTTP Requests using get/post?